# async postback using standard button in updatepanel

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

Using an update panel, I am attempting to perform an Async postback with a standard HTML button.

Error:

> Could not find an event named 'onserverclick' on associated control 'btnSearch' for the trigger in UpdatePanel 'UpdatePanel1'.

```
 <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
 </asp:ScriptManager>
 <script type="text/javascript">
            Sys.Application.add_load(BindControlEvents);          
 </script>
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSearch" EventName="onserverclick">
                </asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger>
            </Triggers>
 <ContentTemplate><div class="col-6 col-md-1">
<button runat="server" id="btnSearch" class="btn btn-primary" onserverclick="btnSearch_Click" type="button" title="Search" style="margin-top: 17px">
       <i class="fa fa-search"></i>Search
```

Comment: `asp:Button` doesn't have `onserverclick` event. it has `onClick` (which runs at server) and `onClientClick`

Comment: Thanks for reply... I am not used asp:Button, it is a html button which have <i> tag.. it is work but the changes by jquey not work. For example I hide a textbox by changing drop down when I click the button its show, the hide not effect after that again I have to change drop down option.. any help....